# How to Remove Image Resizing in HTML

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, image-resizing, drupal-theming

I'm not sure if this website is re-sizing images via HTML, or if the image size is automatically added to the code.

If the images are being re-sized, this would need to be fixed, because it slows page load times.

Here is an [example page](http://www.gesoftware.com/predictivity/rail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override default [theme_image](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) and remove `width` and `height` properties, or set their values to `auto`.

Example:

```
// In your theme's template.php file
function [YOUR_THEME]_image($variables) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);

  foreach (array('alt', 'title') as $key) {
    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
    }
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that there is re-sizing happening via html?

Comment: No, it's not what I'm saying :). You asked `How to Remove Image Resizing in HTML`, and the answer explains how. But in order to create image style presets, you should do that from `?q=admin/config/media/image-styles`.